# How to open a URL in Windows 8 in a specified browser

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've created a JavaScript Windows Store blank app, and added the following code to launch Google in a default browser.

```
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.google.com")
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(url);
```

What can I do to specify a specific browser to launch Google in? Is it possible? I think I read somewhere that I can't do this, but I can't seem to find that forum any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it.  Your app doesn't know anything about which browsers are installed, so it won't be able to target a specific one, even if the framework allowed for this (which it doesn't).  The other thing to bear in mind is that your user should be in control (in this case by specifying their default browser).  You should not try to override this choice.

Comment: Here here... user should be in control. How angry would you be if you had an app that forced you into a browser you didn't like to use?